# Odoo Record Rules to filter for subordinates leave

Tags: odoo, record-rules

I am a Odoo newbie.

I have used the following rule: **['|',('employee_id.user_id','=',user.id),('employee_id.parent_id.user_id','=',user.id)]** to only allow employees to view their leave applications and have only managers see the subordinates leave applications. However, while applying this rule  to everyone (**Globally**), I would like to still have HR Managers (**those given Manager roles i believe its base.group_hr_manager in the module**) to be able to see every ones leave request ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
[(1, '=', 1)]
```

And add HR Manager in groups